# Returning List<string> from XDocument

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

```
<dataList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <headers>
  <header>Template name</header> 
  </headers>
 <rows>
 <row>
  <data>Template1</data> 
  </row>
 <row>
  <data>Template2</data> 
  </row>
  </rows>
</dataList>



        XDocument xml = new XDocument();
        xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlstringFromAbove);
        List<string> list = (from c in xml.Elements("data")
                             select c.Value).ToList();
```

This code returns an empty list.

How can I get a list of strings containing Template1 and Template2 ?

Answer (score 3):

The `Elements` method only returns immediate children, use `Descendants` instead:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlstringFromAbove);
var list = (from c in xml.Descendants("data") select c.Value).ToList();
```